# Javascript closures - behavior of overridden functions from the global scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

This question is more on javascript principle.

```
function done(){ console.log('done defined with `function done(){ ...`'); }
var done = function(){ console.log('done defined with `var done = ...`'); }
done = function(){ console.log('without `var`, just `done = ...`'); }
```

If defined right inside `<script>` tags, will they all do the same thing, right?

But if I place them in a closure `(function(){` **function definintion goes here** `}())` will any of these three types override either the globally defined function **done()** or any other **done()** functions that are defined inside their respective closures?

If the question above doesn't make sense, here's to rephrasing;

- is the following code supposed to do the same thing in any JS runtime?
- `eval`-ing code anywhere executes that particular code within the context or the global scope?
- how can a `setTimeout` call be configured so that the code between its "quotes" executes to inside the scope where that particular `setTimeout` has been called (please see second timeout inside `for` below)? I mean is there any other way besides defining window.blabla functions and telling them to delete themselves after they run?

  ```
  function done(d){ console.log('cha cha cha: '+d); }
  setTimeout( function(){ done(2); }, 3500 );

  for(i=0; i<10; i++){
      (function(){
          done = function(x){ console.log('done #'+i+' sais: '+x); }
          setTimeout(function(){ done(i*2); },2500);
          setTimeout(function(){ done(i*2); }.toString()+'(); ',2500);
      }());
  }
  ```

Comment: Don't use your second timeout approach. Or is there any reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial question on general behaviour:

- `var done =` and `function done` do basicaly the same thing. They will shadow the outer definition in the inner scope but they will not replace it on the outer scope.
- `done =` will set the corresponding `done` variable in scope or will create a global variable if such a variable does not exist and the program is not running in strict mode.
- At a global level, outside any function, `var done =` and `done =` should work the same, but they work differently in IE if you try to use the variable in another script tag (stick to `var =` - its better anyway).

As for the very evil setTimeout and eval questions:

- Yes, I guess this kind of stuff should be standardized enough to work the same everywhere. I would still test it anyway. (Or you could use a different solution, given how evil eval is)
- *eval* runs code in the current scope (using deep black magic to do so). If you want to run code on the global scope you can use `new Function` instead.
- In order to have the settimeout run the string in the curent scope you can add the *eval* yourself:

  ```
  var done = function(d){ console.log('outer done', d); };

  (function(){
      var done = function(x){ console.log('inner done', x); };

      setTimeout(function(){ done(1); }, 200);           //inner done
      setTimeout('done(2)', 400);                        //outer done
      setTimeout(function(){ eval('done(3)'); }, 600);   //inner done
  }());
  ```
- Once again, why are you eval-ing things in the setTimeouts? This all sounds profoundly evil!

Comment: Most complete answer, thanks.

It's not evil, though I'm crossing a monkey with a Hummer, telling the monkey to do something from within the Hummer, in order to keep all my code within the same JS project I had to do some crazy things, such as passing functions via JSON. It's also a matter of syntax highlighting.

Comment: Well, here where I live crossing a monkey with a Hummer is most definetly considered evil :P

Comment: for the setTimeout with eval you do not need eval you just bind the function inside eval to this which is the scope where you are.

Comment: @helly0d: I know and that is what I do in the first example. The eval inside the settimeout is to compare with the case that passes a string to settimeout.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between `var done` and `done`, because the latter implicates `window.done` and can be `delete`d therefore.

The statement `done = foobar;` will overwrite the next "done" variable in the scope chain. If there is a local `var`, it changes that, if there is a global one, it will overwrite that one, anf if not it will create a new global one.
All these will not affect any private variables in other scopes (closures).

Answer (score 0):

One note on your first block. When you give a function a name as you have in the first line, that function name is parsed at compile time and available anywhere within the scope. If you simply assign a function to a variable, then that function (i.e., variable) is only available at runtime **after** the definition, **even** if you give it a name.

For example:

```
// this is valid
foo();
function foo(){ console.log("foo"); }

// this throws an error...
bar();
var bar = function (){ console.log("bar"); };

// ...and so does this...
baz();
var bat = function baz(){ console.log("bazbat"); };

// ...and this!
baz();
```